# Can MySql determine 'bearing' between two records with latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql, gis, latitude-longitude, bearing

I am trying to find/store the 'bearing' of streets in a table I have.  I can provide for each street the first building address latiutude and longitude and the same for the last building. Can MySql somehow process a compass bearing with this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to do this, but if you can write it as an equation using the two coordinates, you can put that in the query.

Comment: If you google "calculate compass bearing from lat long" you'll get plenty of results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a stored function that computes the initial compass heading (also known to navigators as the forward azimuth) to move from one point `(lat1,lon1)` to another point `(lat2, lon2)` on the (assumed spherical) globe.

It's based on formulae in this web page.  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `initial_bearing`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initial_bearing`(
        lat1 DOUBLE, lon1 DOUBLE, 
        lat2 DOUBLE, lon2 DOUBLE
     ) RETURNS DOUBLE
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Returns the initial bearing, in degrees, to follow the great circle route
             from point (lat1,lon1), to point (lat2,lon2)'
    BEGIN

    RETURN (360.0 + 
      DEGREES(ATAN2(
       SIN(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2)),
       COS(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))-SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*
            COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))
      ))
     ) % 360.0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you have a table containing the columns of FLOAT type called `lat1`,`lon1`,`lat2`, `lon2`,`bearing`, you could use this function to set the `bearing` column from the others with this query.

```
UPDATE table name SET bearing = initial_bearing(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
```

This query, lacking a WHERE clause, will update every row of the table.

Comment: Thank you. I created my test table which has for each named recort MinLatitude, MaxLatitude, MinLongitude, MaxLongitude and a field for the bearing output. Do you have any idea how I'd call a function like this to step through that table and use the min/max lat/long to output/store bearing?